# Sequence of continued fractions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, number-theory, continued-fractions

Define a sequence like below 
$$\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\\x_n=2+\frac{k_1}{2+\frac{k_2}{\ddots+\frac{k_n}{2}}}$$and 
$$k_1,k_2,...,k_n \in \{5,20\}$$ 
What is the $max\{x_n\},min\{x_n\} ?$
  I tried to put all of them $5,20$ but , get stuck . The key answer  is $max=10, min=2.5$
can you help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't stop: 6 questions in 6 hours ? Do you have time for you in between ?

Comment: @JeanMarie :friday is my free day . usually I am solving in a week ,and my questions begin to appear in my free time .

Comment: $2 + \frac{k_1}{a}$ is large when $k_1$ is large and $a$ small, and it's small when $k_1$ is small and $a$ large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $a_i>0$
$$2+\frac{k_1}{a_1}\quad\text{is maximized when $k_1=20$ and $a_1$ is minimized}$$
$$a_1=2+\frac{k_2}{a_2}\quad\text{is minimized when $k_2=5$ and $a_2$ is maximized}$$
$$a_2=2+\frac{k_3}{a_3}\quad\text{is maximized when $k_3=20$ and $a_3$ is minimized}$$
and so on. Therefore, $\lim\sup_{n\to \infty}x_n$ is given by
$$2+\frac{20}{2+\frac{5}{2+\frac{20}{2+\frac{5}{2+...}}}}$$
A similar argument works when you want to find the minimum.

Comment: Actually, that's the $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n$. The max is simply $x_1$, using the strategy outlined here.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Thanks, edited.